# First-time signed up user is created only after reloading the app in React Native w/ AWS Amplify-GraphQL

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

i'm using AWS Amplify Cognito + Graphql in order to sign in and sign up users to my app. In order to do so, i wrapped it in a HOC `Authenticator` component, switching from `withAuthenticator`. Since i made this switch to `Authenticator`, now newly signed up users who sign in for the very first time need to reload to app to fetch their account data, because, during this very first signin, the app does not  fetch their `sub` (ID). I believe that the reason for this is (i noticed this particular behavior) that their user table are now getting created in DynamoDB only after reloading the app, and not during the signup process as it was before.
Any idea what might be the cause for this issue?
`App.js` is as following:

```
const App= () => {

     useEffect( () => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
       const userInfo = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: true});

            const newUser = {
              id: userInfo.attributes.sub, 
              title: "User",
            }

      try { 
        await API.graphql(graphqlOperation( createUser, { input: newUser } ) )
        console.log("User Created")
      } catch (err) { console.log(err)}

     };

    fetchUser()
  }, [])
```

SignUp.js

```
async function onSubmitSignup() {
    const {email, preferred_username, password} = values;
    try {
      const user = await Auth.signUp({
        username: email,
        password,
        attributes: {
          preferred_username,
        },
      });

      const newUser = {
        id: 1235352346456, 
        title: "User",
      }
      try { 
        await API.graphql(graphqlOperation( createUser, { input: newUser } ) )
        console.log("User Created")
      } catch (err) { console.log("enr3",err)};

      props.onStateChange('confirmSignUp', user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
      setError(error.message);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to create user after signing up, not when the component is first rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Create User right after Sign Up process. In your code, you're trying to create user every time you access the website.

```
const res = await Auth.signUp({
  username: email,
  password,
  attributes: {
    "custom:username": username,
  },
});

const user = {
  id: username,
  sub: res.userSub,
  email,
};

await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createUser, { input: user }));
```

Comment: Thanks, when i try the above solution and perform a create mutation by wrapping it in a try and catch statement, it will throw the following error:  "Error- no current user". Any idea why this happens?

Comment: mhm, did you allow unauthenticated user to create user in `GraphQL` schema?

Comment: I'm currently trying with both, either unauthenticated or authenticated ones, it still gives me the No User error if i add the create User snippet in SignUp.js. Whereas if i keep it in App.js it works but user gets created after first app reload because it's unable to fetch sub.